# How to allow client to access any static file from Node.js + Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

This is my index.js file called as node.js server :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
serv.listen(PORT);
```

I'm developping a client app with Angular, when I build the application, I get many files for client. I put them on client repertory.

To allow client to access to these files, I added this code :

```
app.get('/main-es5.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/main-es5.js');});
app.get('/main-es2015.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/main-es2015.js');});
app.get('/polyfills-es5.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/polyfills-es5.js');});
app.get('/polyfills-es2015.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/polyfills-es2015.js');});
app.get('/runtime-es5.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/runtime-es5.js');});
app.get('/runtime-es2015.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/runtime-es2015.js');});
app.get('/styles-es5.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/styles-es5.js');});
app.get('/styles-es2015.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/styles-es2015.js');});
app.get('/vendor-es5.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/vendor-es5.js');});
app.get('/vendor-es2015.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/vendor-es2015.js');});

app.get('/main-es5.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/main-es5.js.map');});
app.get('/main-es2015.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/main-es2015.js.map');});
app.get('/polyfills-es5.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/polyfills-es5.js.map');});
app.get('/polyfills-es2015.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/polyfills-es2015.js.map');});
app.get('/runtime-es5.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/runtime-es5.js.map');});
app.get('/runtime-es2015.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/runtime-es2015.js.map');});
app.get('/styles-es5.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/styles-es5.js.map');});
app.get('/styles-es2015.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/styles-es2015.js.map');});
app.get('/vendor-es5.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/vendor-es5.js.map');});
app.get('/vendor-es2015.js.map', function(req, res) {res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/vendor-es2015.js.map');});
```

Without this large block of code, client seems not to have access to it.

How can I refactor it?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying  `deploy-url` when building your app

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url=/client
```

This will tell angular to load the scritps and assets from `/client` path, instead of root path

Since you've already got the following line, this should work.

```
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

Comment: Hey David, thank you for your answer.
I tried your specification, and it didn't work, however I found this : 
`ng buid --prod --baseHref=client`
client is my static folder where I put the client files for express

Comment: Yes it works. Server side, I give access client to my folder 'client' only with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));`

Answer (score 0):

**Add** this to your code,
and the client can access any file within the project.

> ```
> app.use('*', (req, res) => {
>     res.sendFile(__dirname + req.originalUrl)
> })
> ```

Comment: That's dangerous as then the client could use the path `/.env` and gain access to private keys. It's better to let the client access a specific folder then the entire directory.